# How to analyse memory distribution in a process?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I have a running (private) server which use about 1.1G virtual memory (1.0G physical memory) . Though I have the source code of the server, while I want to figure out any better solution that I can use to get a big picture of the memory distribution among objects in the server? Some thing like this:

```
HashTable: 50%, 500M

PlayerCache: 20%, 200M

OtherA: 10%, 100M

...
```

where pointer may be in the object and points to dynamic allocated memorys.

Comment: You can do it by attaching a debugger to the server process and examining the sizes of variables.

Comment: What is that server doing? Is it some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) program? Is it multi-threaded? So **edit your question** to improve it and get better answers

Comment: Without additional details this question is too broad and unclear

Comment: In what programming language is the server written? Do you understand its source code, and are you willing to improve that source code (and instrument  it somehow) ?  Please **edit your question** even **more**; explain in a few paragraphs what is the server doing, some details about the source code (programming language, size of source code, familiarity with it). Perhaps show some of your source code in the question (and preferably some [MCVE] related to your code...)

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, you could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) (BTW, [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) are all using `/proc/` and are useful to you).

So if your server [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has [pid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) 1234, you could try `pmap 1234` and `cat /proc/1234/maps` in your terminal to understand the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your process. Try also `cat /proc/1234/status`

Remember that processes run in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and each of them has its own virtual address space, and that the physical RAM is a resource managed by the kernel. You might be interested by the [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size)

**You won't have a report detailing dynamic memory usage per type, or per variable** (because that *does not make any sense in general*: for example, in C, a given `malloc`-ed memory zone could be dereferenced thru casts of different types and be accessible -perhaps indirectly- thru several variables). You might use [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) (it could give statistics related to size of memory zones) if your program is using [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

You could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), very useful to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

You could modify the source code of your server to handle and do some accounting, in your specific ways, of the [heap allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP) it is doing. For example, if you code in C++, you could modify the constructors and destructors of your classes to increment and decrement some `static` or global counters, or provide some class-specific `operator new` and `delete`.  Heap memory consumption is a whole-program property (and is not tied, *in general*, to a *specific* type or variable). Some programs have their own (type-specific) [allocators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B)) or use arena based or [region based allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management).

Read also something about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), e.g. the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/), to get useful concepts and terminology and techniques (e.g. [tracing GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection), [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference), [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference), [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), etc..). They matter even for [manual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management).

Memory management and allocation is specific to every program, particularly in programming languages like C or C++ (or Rust) with manual memory management where *conventions* matter a lot and are specific to every program. Study the source code of existing various [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) servers (e.g. [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), [Lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/), [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server), [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), [Git](http://git-scm.com/), ...) and you'll find out that each of them has different conventions about memory management.

Comment: Why the downvote, since I improved my answer to explain that OP's question is too general to get a useful specific answer, but I tried to give some hints.

Comment: I asked then deleted [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367414/841108) related to my answer above. I am a bit irritated by downvotes without comments